# show only exact match bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to extract a line from fstab and print 3rd column

mountpint=/var

```
#grep -w "$mountpoint" /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv /var ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-vloglv /var/log ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-vartmp /var/tmp ext4 defaults 0 0
```

but it showing all lines that contain "/var" but I want only exact match
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv /var ext4 defaults 0 0

How can I extract the line ?

Comment: one option would be to `grep /var | grep -v /var/`

Comment: Require whitespace around the mountpoint: `grep "[[:space:]]/var[[:space:]]"`. But this really sounds like a job for `awk -v mountpoint="$mountpoint" '$2==mountpoint {print $3}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for awk! This program lets you do operation on columns of data (separated by space by default). The `$2` and `$3` here represents the second and third columns.

The `-v` option is to pass a bash variable to our awk script

```bash
awk -v m=$mountpoint '{if ($2 == m) print $3}' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: You could move the condition outside: `$2 == m { print $3 }`

Comment: #:~> awk -v m=$mountpoint '{if ($2 == m) print $3}' /etc/fstab
ext4
#:~> awk -v m=$mountpoint '$2 == m { print $3 }' /etc/fstab
ext4

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to include the space at your grep pattern

```
# grep "/var\ " /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv /var ext4 defaults 0 0
```